# href click2dial:9898989898 not working in IE9 show modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am opening a modal dialog with window.showModalDialog. My page is in AngularJs.

I have a simple link tag

```
<a ng-href="click2dial:2014559867">c2d</a>
```

clicking on that link does not work when the page is open in modal dialog.

if the page is opened directly in the browser that link works.

Is angularjs intercepting url change ?

Comment: Can you create a jfiddle?